# count # of new records in SQL table EACH DAY, over a 90 day window

Tags: sql

I am needing to count the number of **new** records that show up each day over a 90 day period. I can use the following query to get distinct record counts over that period of time:

```
select date, count(distinct item) as item_count
from table
where date between '20191220' and '20200320'
group by 1
```

I can also write a query to pull the number of new records between only two different dates using "not in (select.. where date is yesterday..)". What I am confused by is how can I do this for each day over a 90 day period? Ideally the output is:

```
date        new_records
20200320    1234
20200319    54
...         ...
20191220    1345
```

Sorry if it was not clear.. new record means that the item was not there in the previous day. I am using Snowflake

Comment: Please explain how you define *new* record.

Comment: Tag the DBMS that you are using.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. New record means that the item was not there in the previous day. I am using Snowflake

Answer (score 1):

If you mean the first time an item appears, then you can use two levels of aggregation:

```
select first_date, count(*)
from (select item, min(date) as first_date
      from t
      group by item
     ) i
group by first_date;
```

You can include a `where` clause in the outer query if you want the overall first.  You can include it in the inner query if you want the first time during the time period specified.